# Editor placeholder in source file tableview.dequeueReusableCell

Tags: swift, xcode

Keeps getting this error:

> 'Editor placeholder in source file'

on the line `tableView.dequeueReusableCell`, and have no clue what went wrong. Please help how to get rid off this error. The function prototype is suggested by Xcode. Can't remove `withIdentifier` in the `tableView.dequeueReusableCell` as some people suggested to solve this problem.

```
func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BasicCell", for: IndexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = filters[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

[image]

Comment: `indexPath` (lowercased).

Comment: `IndexPath` in the function call is still using the placeholder value (notice the background highlighting).  You need to replace it with `indexPath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at where the error is. It's on the `IndexPath` part after `for:`.

You have to replace that placeholder with a valid `IndexPath` reference such as with the `indexPath` parameter.